# Matlab imwarp, images don't fit

Tags: image, matlab

I'm using Matlab R2013a to align two similar images. The output looks fine except that both images don't fit due to a x,y misalignment. I reason that this is due to the rotation of the image. Is there an easy way to "center" the images such that after affine transformation both images can be overlayed?

```
Transformation = imregtform(uint8(A),uint8(B),'affine', ...
                        optimizer,metric);
[X RB] = imwarp(A,Transformation,'OutputView',imref2d(size(A)));
```

B is the original images. A gets registered to B. After affine transformation X contains a rotated and scaled image but need to be aligned on the x and y axes to perfectly fit A.

Thanks for any hint!
Durin

Comment: How did you specify `optimizer` and `metric`?

Comment: [optimizer,metric] = imregconfig('multimodal');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the OutputView you want size(B) since B is your reference image and you want the resampled version of A to have the same size as B.

Answer (score 3):

Set the size of output image of `imwarp` function, X, same as that of input image B that you want to overlay X on.

```
X = imwarp(A, Transformation, 'OutputView', imref2d( size(B) ));
```

You can then use `imfuse` to overlap the two images and display it using `imshow`:

```
falseColorOverlay = imfuse( B, X);
imshow( falseColorOverlay, 'initialMagnification', 'fit');
```

B will be colored green while X will be colored magenta.